# kth smallest element using Randomized select

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms, selection-problem

I have recently started studying Randomized algorithms on my own. I am refering to Rajiv motwani - randomized algorithms book.

Objective - find kth smallest element using radomized select in $O(n^\frac{3}{4} \log n)$ time

> My attempt:

From array of n elements, pick randomly $n^\frac{3}{4}$ elements. Now from k th smallest element, at distance of $\sqrt n$ on either sides, I call sample point as $R_l, R_h$ respectively and elements at that place in array are $a, b$ respectively.

Now i pick all elements between a and b and call as P. If P falls in middle, then kth smallest element will be in right P picked up.

Aim is to find bad probability - probability that my choosen P does not contain kth smallest element. THis happens when all $n^\frac{3}{4}$ random points picked up are either on left side of kth smallest element or on right side of kth smallest element ie., my P will be on left side of kth smallest element or on right side of kth smallest element

Applying chebeshev inequality

$P(|\bar x - x| > \epsilon) < \frac{\text{Var}(\bar x^2)}{\epsilon^2}$ , $\bar x $ is Expectation of $n^\frac{3}{4}$ points falling on left side of kth smallest element and $\text{Var}(\bar x^2)$ is the corresponding variance.

ie., what is the probability that all my $n^\frac{3}{4}$ points are at $\epsilon$ distance on left side of kth smallest element or on right side of kth smallest element?

But Rajiv Motwani book considers

$\epsilon = \sqrt n$ which means that all $n^\frac{3}{4}$ points fall on left side of $x-\sqrt n$ and $x+\sqrt n$. Ideally should it be on left side of x and right side of x at some small epsilon distance? Kindly clarify here.

[image]